# Модифицировать регулярку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка которая выбирает все что находится между скобок вместе с ними, у меня никак не получается добавить исключение что бы пропускало скобку со словом table внутри. Может кто поможет.

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
'~\[(?![^][]*table)[^][]*]~'
```

или, если слово `table` должно быть целым словом:

```
'~\[(?![^][]*\btable\b)[^][]*]~'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/H7FkwK/2)

**Подробности**

- `\[` - символ `[`
- `(?![^][]*\btable\b)` - негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который, при наличии совпадения шаблона, отменяет совпадение:

  - `[^][]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`
  - `\btable\b` - целое слово `table` (если проверка на целое слово необязательна, удалите `\b`)
- `[^][]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`
- `]` - символ `]`.

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/U8QgsL):

```
$re = '/\[(?![^][]*\btable\b)[^][]*]/';
$str = '[kjkj] jkhjkhjk [table] [wedfwefwef] [bgfghfghf] [fvdfvd][sdfsd] [terms] [5465456] jkhjkhjkh';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches[0]); // => Array ( [0] => [kjkj] )
```